# Timer program in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I have to make a timer program which will start from 00:03:30
and stop at 0
at 2:30 seconds I have to make beep sound How can I achieve the program in objective c

Comment: Please read the [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code:

**ViewController.h**

```
NSDate *startDate, *beepSoundDate, *endDate;
NSTimer *timer;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)setTimer
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
    startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"00:03:30"];
    beepSoundDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"00:02:30"];
    endDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"00:00:00"];

//    startDate = [NSDate date];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(getTimerInterval)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];

}
-(void)getTimerInterval
{

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [offsetComponents setSecond:-1];
    startDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:startDate options:0];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
    NSString *timeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:startDate];
    NSLog(@"%@",timeString);

    if(startDate == beepSoundDate)
    {
        // Play beep sound
        NSLog(@"************************************");
    }

    if(startDate == endDate)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
}
```

You can call **setTimer** when you want to **start** your **timer**.